# Why didn't Jack Sparrow make a duplicate of the key?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

[Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man's Chest (2006)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0383574/) revolves around finding the chest which contains Davy Jones' heart. Central to the story is finding the key which unlocks the chest.

Jack seem to have acquired the information as well as a [diagram of the key](https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Key_to_the_Dead_Man%27s_Chest). Based on which he puts together a crew and sets on the journey.

[image: Key to Davy Jones' chest]

My question is if Jack had the diagram why didn't he got a duplicate made from a key maker?

Is there any supernatural element involved in the original key because it was never explained in the movie?

Comment: Sometimes, a [McGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) just **has** to be there, otherwise there's no plot ;) If he'd just wandered down to the local mall to get a key cut, then straight off to Isla Cruces, the movie would have been a whole lot shorter.

Comment: [Previously asked on SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/232219/98028), though there are no answers so far.

Comment: As far as we know, the Key and Chest's maker/origin remains unknown: https://pirates.fandom.com/wiki/Key_to_the_Dead_Man%27s_Chest

Comment: @Tetsujin: I understand your point. But isn't it so obvious. In a universe where Pirates rule the sea how hard was it to dupe a key.

Comment: @Jenayah: It's a cosmic coincidence that we both choose the same exact image. :D

Comment: The story doesn't depend on the availability of locksmiths. That's the point. If they could just get a key cut right there & then, there would be no plot left… all the bit about trying to steal the key… rescue the girl.. would be missing. The movie would be 'find drawing, make key, get box. The End'

Comment: @DarthLocke: Yes I aware of it. My and now Jenayah's question is regarding duping it.

Comment: @Tetsujin: What am looking for is involvement of some spell/supernatural element as there was on Aztec's Gold coins. They could be duped too.

Comment: No, you're looking for a way round the McGuffin. There can never be a way round a McGuffin. That's its entire point. Lion, Witch, no wardrobe. The end.

Comment: @Rahul given the amount of clear shots there are of the drawing, not that much of a coincidence I'd say

Comment: I understand, but what I'm saying is that there isn't in canon, because the source of either key or the chest is unknown. So there is no answer other than that as of now.

Comment: How do you know that the key is _precisely_ copied? How do you know if it's to scale? How certain are you that the key hole is cylindrical?

Comment: Two dimensional sketch of a 3-d object that has to be precisely the exact size, shape, depth, etc to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the unique design of the key combined with the fact that there was magic involved stopped Jack from duplicating or making a new key. He had the "drawing of a key" and theoretically could have had somebody make one for him, but again: A McGuffin does have to be there,if it begins to exist. I think maybe Jack didn't know anybody to make a key or even didn't trust anybody to make a key, which is more likely. Or the lock could have been imbued with some sort of magic? It's unclear, but I think most likely Jack didn't trust anybody to make him a copy without telling Davy's men. Jack Sparrow trusts nobody, not even himself.

Comment: While I would agree with anyone that we don't have a ton of evidence still to prove anything, I think this answer is logical and attempts to cover most of the bases. I do think Flater also makes excellent point about the diagram may not be to scale, but I also think your one point about the key being "magical" makes a whole lot of sense too. 1+